# Python with GPS IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x, gnat, gnat-gps

I'm trying to set up Gnat Programming Studio IDE, to do some Python dev. I have Python 3.5 on my machine, and I have started a new project in GPS and selected Python as the language, but when I tried a simple Hello World, I got the following message.

```
warning: no compiler specified for language "Python", ignoring all its sources
```

Any idea how to fix? I'm assuming I need to link the Python interpreter to GPS but I don't know how!

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a way to set the project interpreter?